# Is it possible to modify by reference the content of a FloatBuffer?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, floatbuffer

I initialized the content of my `FloatBuffer` with an array of `Float` once. And then modify the `Floats` that I have put in, I would expect that it modifies also the values in the `FloatBuffer` but I obtain a weird result.

Am I doing wrong ? Is it possible to do that ?

EDIT: My mistake, I understood that Float was immutable so this is a normal behaviour. So my question would be, is there a way to fill FloatBuffer with mutable float wrappers so that I can easily modify my FloatBuffer content by reference ? Or is there a nicer alternative to FloatBuffer for OpenGL data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

The FloatBuffer has methods that do what you want if I understand you correctly.

With the FloatBuffer you can set its position by calling the [position method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position(int)) (don't forget to return it to 0 when done, opengl es needs it at 0 if I remember correctly). Then you can read or write to that position with [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#get()) and [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#put(float)) methods.

So if you need to update the content of native memory you can do so from the FloatBuffer that allocated it like so:

```
    floatBuffer.position(position);
    floatBuffer.put(data, startIndex, count);
    floatBuffer.position(0);
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I want to put a value once, and change the value that I've put from outside and have the value also changed in the FloatBuffer. But I think this is not possible with FloatBuffers since they only keep 'float' values and you can't do this with primitive types,  so I can't change their value by reference

Comment: FloatBuffers allocate to native memory, where opengl es needs its data stored. The allocated memory is saved as an array therefore it is a reference. If you want a java object to access directly native memory I don't think it is possible.